# $_GET value is losing it's space

Tags: search

I have a custom search form:

```
<div class="searchHeader">
    <div class="searchHeaderHolder">
        <input type="checkbox" id="search-form-checkbox" aria-hidden="true">
        <form action="/" method="get" id="searchform">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="search" name="s" required>
                <a href="#" class="closeSearch"></a>
            </div>
            <label for="search"><?php echo __('Search', 'Swoo'); ?></label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I submit the form, the spaces are removed from the input.

Example, if I submit `hello world`, my url would become `http://example.com/en/?s=helloworld`...

Before submitting, the value is correct when I test it in the chrome console:

```
var search = document.getElementById('search');
search.value; // hello world
```

Does anyone know what's causing the space to disappear?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was the WPML redirection that is removing the spaces from my input.

To fix it, I've added the language code in the form action.

```
<form action="/<?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE; ?>/" method="get" id="searchform">
```